# Magick convert through subprocess, Converting tiff images to pdf increases the size by 20 times

Tags: python-3.x, imagemagick, python-imaging-library

I tried using density but it didn't help. The original TIFF image is 459 kB but when it gets converted to PDF the size changes to 8446 KB.

```
commands = ['magick', 'convert']
commands.extend(waiting_list["images"][2:])
commands.append('-adjoin')
commands.append(combinedFormPathOutput)
process = Popen(commands, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
process.communicate()
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14V3vKRcyyEx1U23nVC13DDyxGAYOpH-6/view?usp=sharing

Its not teh above code but the below PIL code which is causing the image to increase

```
images = []
filepath = 'Multi_document_Tiff.tiff'
image = Image.open(filepath)
   
    if filepath.endswith('.tiff'):
            imagepath = filepath.replace('.tiff', '.pdf')
            for i, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(image)):
                page = page.convert("RGB")
                images.append(page)
            if len(images) == 1:
                images[0].save(imagepath)
            else:
                images[0].save(imagepath, save_all=True, append_images=images[1:])
            image.close()
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without having a sample image...

Comment: Hi @xenoid, I have added the image now

Comment: What you added appears as a single-page 200K PNG  (which IM converts to a 200K PDF). You have to upload your tiff to a site that won't reencode it (Google Drive, DropBox...)

Comment: Please use the proper, internationally agreed, SI units. One kilobyte is 1 kB. One megabyte is 1 MB. One megabit is 1 Mb.

Comment: @xenoid - I added the link to google drive for the image

Comment: Link is incorrect, it's not to the file,  nor to your specific drive, but to whoever is logged in own drive.

Comment: @xenoid, please check now

Answer (score 1):

When I run

```
convert Multi_document_Tiff.tiff -adjoin Multi_document.pdf
```

I get  a 473881 bytes PDF that contains the 10 pages of the TIFF. If I run

```
convert Multi_document_Tiff.tiff Multi_document_Tiff.tiff Multi_document_Tiff.tiff  -adjoin Multi_document.pdf
```

I get a 1420906 bytes PDF that contains 30 pages (three copies of your TIFF).

So obviously if you pass several input files to IM it will coalesce them in the output file.

You code does:

```
commands.extend(waiting_list["images"][2:])
```

So it seems it is passing a list of files to IM, and the output should be the accumulation of all these files, which can be a lot bigger that the size of the first file.

So:

1. did you check the content of the output PDF?
2. did you check the list of files which is actually passed?

Comment: Hi @xenoid, I ran the test with just one file , and the content of the pdf and tiff file match just the size of the pdf is quite large. Could you also help with the entire code which you used to run the line 'convert Multi_document_Tiff.tiff -adjoin Multi_document.pdf', may be that could help reaching  out the solution

Comment: I checked the input and output files , the input and output contains 10 pages of pdf

Comment: 1. what version of IM are you using? 2. Can you reproduce the problem with just a shell execution?

Comment: I am not using IM but using it through sub process, it is my project code which also uses PIL  and pdf2 image

Comment: Which is why we have to factor out the project code, and run just the core IM thing.

Comment: Hi @xenoid, I tried running it through image magick and the pdf file size is just 455 kb, so not sure why the python code is creating such a big file

Comment: If you print `commands` before calling `Popen()` what does it say?

Comment: Hi @Xenoid it is not the magick but PIL causing PDF to grow in size, I have added the PIl code in the question, could you please help with thsi

Comment: Sorry but going forward I won't look at anything which isn't the complete code since I suspect the problem is more in the design than in specific bit of the code.

Comment: Sorry @Xenoid I wasn't sure which part was causing issue only when you suggested to run the core IM thing , I came to know to that IM specific code was not the cause of the issue, so many thanks for your help. I have managed to get the issue fixed